# Queueing theory for multiple nodes with different service time

Tags: probability-theory, queueing-theory

I am looking for a suitable queueing model consisting following behaviors

1. the arrival rate will be exponentially distributed
2. there will be different types of jobs with different priorities.
3. the service time is same for all jobs of a same category.
4. there will be 1 server

I need the response time distribution for the above scenario.

I looked for variation of M/D/1 queue but couldn't found similar to my required model. Can anyone suggest me some resources.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Frank Kelly has a book that describes generalizations of Jackson networks that may be relevant.  Network calculus can also treat exactly what you state via bounding analysis.

Comment: For just a single queue with multiple classes of traffic, there are standard M/G/1 type results for priority service, see for example chapter 3 in the online book _Data Networks_ by Bertsekas and Gallager.

Comment: You are welcome. I found the link to the _Data Networks_ book, it is here (Section 3.5.3 considers priority queueing): http://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/datanets.html